# android ArrayList not adding items as expected

Tags: java, android, mobile

Code :
public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Communicator {
.
.
.

```
 public void sendToBill(Items items) {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        homeFragment.addToBill(items);
    }


}



public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<Items> billList = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
.

 public void addToBill(Items item) {
        billList.add(item);

    }
}
```

and from here am calling it

```
final Communicator communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();
  communicator.sendToBill(item);
```

and i can see the log but it is always one item

Logs :

```
2020-10-16 06:53:56.363 16662-16662/com.example.iszo_dev D/counting: White wine dry
```

Comment: I would start by logging the ArrayList before and after you've added the new item to ensure it gets added. How does the sendToBill Interface now what item to use?

Answer (score 1):

You're actually creating a new object reference of HomeFragment every time you call the sendToBill(item) function which eventually initialize your HomeFragment every time and initializes your HomeFragment's billsList also in result there will be only one latest item every time after calling the sendToBill function.

You have to make a single global reference of HomeFragment in your NavActivity rather than creating a new reference each time.